# iTunes Connect status not changed as said in E-Mail

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have submitted the app to app store via XCODE 7 and it had changed the status to "waiting for review". After few hours latter, I got email from apple

> iTunes Connect: Version 3.0.0 (3.0.1) for xxx has completed processing

And they have mentioned to, i can proceed the app store submission. BTW i loged into itunes connect and view the app status. App status has not changed as completed processing. It is still on "waiting for review". Why is that? Does that take some time to change the status?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect: Version 3.0.0 (3.0.1) for xxx has completed processing : The mail is regarding the status of your application you have submitted is completed processing.
What does it me it means actually ?
A: When we upload app to store it contain so many binary need to be processed by apple. You can see this processing in **Activity** tab at **iTunes connect**.

Once the processing is completed you are able to select the build as the build for next version.

The mail is auto generated when processing completed.In your case it might have get delayed due to some reason.

Now the status of your application.

**Waiting for review** : Your application is queue to get reviewed by apple, don't worry it might take time depending upon the traffic of application to be reviewed.

**In Riview** : Will be the next status, and after you will get result (Approved/Rejected)

This might help

App Review Status : https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/

> Once you've submitted your app for review, you can view its status in
>   the My Apps section of iTunes Connect or on the iTunes Connect App for
>   iPhone and iPad. Review times may vary by app. On average, 50% of apps
>   are reviewed in 24 hours and over 90% are reviewed in 48 hours. If
>   your submission is incomplete, review times may be further delayed or
>   your app may be rejected. Once your app has been reviewed, its status
>   will be updated and you will be notified. For details on viewing and
>   changing your app’s status, read the

Have patients. The status will change soon.
**Keep coding**